# is there any option for a mouse hover in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Is there any options for mouse over in google sheets programmatically ? that mouse hover have to happen without setting the note manually. for little more clarification am adding a google sheet along with this query.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJAVZ0pR9r3oNSQ20lbPvq3RxhaC2feKDV5TVzbA_jk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't any feature for hover in google sheets but there is an alternative to it. You can read it here:

https://support.google.com/docs/thread/5680193?hl=en

The response of "Platinum Product Expert" explains.